# Rails partials empty collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

Is there a way to set the default behavior for a rendering a collection when it's empty.
What I have so far is this:

```
<%= render @entries %>
```

which renders the `_entry.html.erb` partial for each of the entries in the `@entries` list. I would like to print some sort of message, like: 'No Entries Found'. Is there a way of doing so without explicitly writing the entries partial?

Comment: think about View is for data representation, not for logic. What about assignment @entries to a message on a controller side if it's empty? Another approach is take the logic into a helper

Comment: This is view logic... not business logic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this

```
<%= render(@entries) || 'No Entries Found' %>
```

Comment: Can you wrap the entries somehow – for example in a `ul` tag?

Answer (score 6):

First create an empty partial, say `_empty.html.erb`.

Then:

```
<%= render(@entries) || render('empty') %>
```

This way you can customize the empty partial to suite your design.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply append a conditional in the template:

```
<%= render @entries %>
<% if @entries.blank? %>
  No entries found.
<% end %>
```